# Telegram API error USER_DEACTIVATED after authentication

Tags: c#, telegram

I'm using a simple client for Telegram API on C# using TLSharp library.

```
var appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appId"];
var appSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appSecret"];
var clientPhone = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientPhone"];
...
var session = new FileSessionStore();
client = new TelegramClient(int.Parse(appId), appSecret, session, clientPhone);
await client.ConnectAsync();
if (!client.IsUserAuthorized())
{
   hash = await client.SendCodeRequestAsync(clientPhone);
   await client.MakeAuthAsync(clientPhone, hash, code);
}
var state = await client.SendRequestAsync<TLState>(new TLRequestGetState());
```

Here I'm getting exception USER_DEACTIVATED.

So, I tried to get new clean account (with new phone number), login throgth mobile telegram client, after that login to web version, searched some channels, subscribe, sent some messages. After that I tried to login with my client app and at FIRST request got same error.

This issue started to reproduce just this week. Before that I successfully used several test accounts, getting messaged, worked with media and dialogs, no any deactivate errors.

What I'm doing wrong? What limits or policies was broked my application and does exists any way to restore my app?

**UPDATE**

Tried to register new application from another account. After that, repeat same actions with new phone number and another PC with another IP address - banned after first request.

What is going on? Why can telegram blocks my accounts?

Comment: What does the telegram @spambot say?

Comment: How do I ask bot if my account deactivated?

Comment: I'm almost sure you're doing something very wrong with your own app. Telegram doesn't deactivate your account for shared IPs. I have more than 500 accounts (working 24/7) on a single IP and they all work without problem.

Comment: @AliHashemi Could you please tell me what type of client are you using?